# Json value separate from the convert csv to json

Tags: python, json, csv

I want to convert the data to a csv file with python json, after my run went well as the results below.

```
[{"id": "1", "name": "billy", "job": "web-develop"}, {"id": "1", "name": "smith", "job": "programming"}]
```

but none the less I think, how to separate json results based "," as shown below.

```
[{"id": "1", "name": "billy", "job": "web-develop"},
{"id": "1", "name": "smith", "job": "programming"}]
```

This myscript

```
import csv
import json
import sys


input = str(sys.argv[1])

csvfile = open(input, 'r')

fieldnames = ("id","name","job")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)    
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )
sys.stdout.write(out)
```

Comment: For a json parser it doesn't matter if there are new lines. If you want them to be there you have to implement it on your own.

If you just want to take a look at the file from time to time i recommend using an editor that displays json in a human readable way.

Comment: @user2393256, okay thanks for the advice , I just wanted to see him be more readable. nice

Comment: @dwiyanto download JSONView to your chrome and open your .json file in your browser. you will be very happy with the result